# Problem with kdenlive

Tags: appmenu, kdenlive

I can't get kdenlive to run here is the output I get:

```
Gtk-Message: 19:42:33.016: Failed to load module "appmenu-gtk-module"
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Could not initialize GLX
KCrash: crashing... crashRecursionCounter = 2
KCrash: Application Name = kdenlive path = /usr/bin pid = 18630
KCrash: Arguments: /usr/bin/kdenlive %U 
KCrash: Attempting to start /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/drkonqi from kdeinit
sock_file=/run/user/1000/kdeinit5__0
Warning: connect() failed: : No such file or directory
KCrash: Attempting to start /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/drkonqi directly
Gtk-Message: 19:42:34.046: Failed to load module "appmenu-gtk-module"
found lsb_release
Using /proc to determine executable path
Executable is: "/usr/bin/kdenlive"
Executable exists: true
Enabling drkonqi crash catching
QSystemTrayIcon::setVisible: No Icon set
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
No XVisualInfo for format QSurfaceFormat(version 2.0, options QFlags<QSurfaceFormat::FormatOption>(), depthBufferSize -1, redBufferSize 1, greenBufferSize 1, blueBufferSize 1, alphaBufferSize 0, stencilBufferSize -1, samples -1, swapBehavior QSurfaceFormat::SwapBehavior(SingleBuffer), swapInterval 1, profile  QSurfaceFormat::OpenGLContextProfile(NoProfile))
Falling back to using screens root_visual.
Sending SIGSTOP to process

[1]+  Stopped                 kdenlive %U
mex@DTZ-Main:~$ Sending SIGCONT to process
QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket 15 and type 'Read', disabling...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please add output of `lsmod | grep drm` to the question. What graphics card do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Install package for [`swrast`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=filename&suite=bionic&section=all&arch=amd64&keywords=swrast&searchon=contents):

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri
```

Fix warnings with [`appmenu-gtk-module`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=amd64&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=appmenu-gtk-module) by installation of:

```
sudo apt-get install appmenu-gtk2-module appmenu-gtk3-module
```

Comment: Thanks, but still getting the same error.